# Make navbar keyboard navigational

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins

On my website, I am unable to get the dropdown for the navigation bar to show when the subpages are select. Click the accessibility icon at the bottom and select keyboard navigation. You can tab through the navbar, if you look on the left bottom corner of the browser (chrome) you can see the subpage urls, but the dropdown won't trigger. Is there jquery I can use to fix this keyboard navigation issue? I want my navbar 100% accessible compliant on desktop and mobile view.

Website: http://stg.alamedactc.org/

Navbar Plugin (I do not want to change):https://wordpress.org/plugins/responsive-menu/

Please see below for the code of my current navbar. It is a plugin, so I will need to use Jquery injections.

```
    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation" aria-label="Main menu" data-userway-font-size="14">
         <div class="menu-main-menu-container" data-userway-font-size="14"><ul id="primary-menu" class="menu" data-userway-font-size="14"><li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-24" data-userway-font-size="14"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/about-us/" data-userway-font-size="16" class="userway-s1-selected">About Us  <i class="arrow down" data-userway-font-size="16"></i></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu" data-userway-font-size="14">
     <li id="menu-item-323" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-323" data-userway-font-size="16"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/about-us/commission/" data-userway-font-size="19" class="">Commission</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-408" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-408" data-userway-font-size="16"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/about-us/committees/" data-userway-font-size="19">Committees</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-405" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-405" data-userway-font-size="16"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/about-us/contact-us/" data-userway-font-size="19">Contact Us</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-324" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-324" data-userway-font-size="16"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/about-us/faqs/" data-userway-font-size="19">FAQs</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-325" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-325" data-userway-font-size="16"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/about-us/financials/" data-userway-font-size="19">Financials</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-401" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-401" data-userway-font-size="16"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/about-us/legislative-program/" data-userway-font-size="19">Legislative Program</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-326" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-326" data-userway-font-size="16"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/about-us/partners/" data-userway-font-size="19">Partners</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-402" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-402" data-userway-font-size="16"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/about-us/staff/" data-userway-font-size="19">Staff</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-29" data-userway-font-size="14"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/planning/" data-userway-font-size="16">Planning  <i class="arrow down" data-userway-font-size="16"></i></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu" data-userway-font-size="14">
     <li id="menu-item-327" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-327" data-userway-font-size="16"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/planning/complete-streets-in-alameda-county/" data-userway-font-size="19">Complete Streets</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-328" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-328" data-userway-font-size="16"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/planning/congestion-management/" data-userway-font-size="19">Congestion Management</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-411" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-411" data-userway-font-size="16"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/planning/countywide-bicycle-ped-plan/" data-userway-font-size="19">Active Transportation</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-329" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-329" data-userway-font-size="16"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/planning/countywide-multi-arterial-plan/" data-userway-font-size="19">Countywide Multimodal Arterial Plan</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-330" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-330" data-userway-font-size="16"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/planning/countywide-transit-plan/" data-userway-font-size="19">Countywide Transit Plan</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-331" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-331" data-userway-font-size="16"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/planning/countywidetransportationplan/" data-userway-font-size="19">Countywide Transportation Plan</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-332" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-332" data-userway-font-size="16"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/planning/goodsmovement/" data-userway-font-size="19">Goods Movement</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-333" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-333" data-userway-font-size="16"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/planning/priority-development-area-investment-and-growth-strategy/" data-userway-font-size="19">Priority Development Area Investment and Growth Strategy</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-410" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-410" data-userway-font-size="16"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/planning/sustainable-communities-technical-assistance/" data-userway-font-size="19">Sustainable Communities Technical Assistance</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-409" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-409" data-userway-font-size="16"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/planning/technology/" data-userway-font-size="19">Technology</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-25" data-userway-font-size="14"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/funding/" data-userway-font-size="16">Funding  <i class="arrow down" data-userway-font-size="16"></i></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu" data-userway-font-size="14">
     <li id="menu-item-5689" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-5689" data-userway-font-size="16"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/funding/fund-sources/" data-userway-font-size="19">Fund Sources</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-5688" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-5688" data-userway-font-size="16"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/funding/funding-opportunities/" data-userway-font-size="19">Funding Opportunities</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-5687" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-5687" data-userway-font-size="16"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/funding/reporting-and-grant-forms/" data-userway-font-size="19">Reporting and Grant Forms</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-48" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-48" data-userway-font-size="14"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/programs-projects/" data-userway-font-size="16">Projects and Programs  <i class="arrow down" data-userway-font-size="16"></i></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu" data-userway-font-size="14">
     <li id="menu-item-7699" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-7699" data-userway-font-size="16"><a href="/programs-projects/" data-userway-font-size="19">Projects</a>
     <ul class="sub-menu" data-userway-font-size="16">
       <li id="menu-item-338" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-338" data-userway-font-size="19"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/programs-projects/bicycle-and-pedestrian/" data-userway-font-size="23">Bicycle and Pedestrian</a></li>
       <li id="menu-item-7082" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-7082" data-userway-font-size="19"><a href="/programs-projects/expresslanes/" data-userway-font-size="23">Express Lanes</a></li>
       <li id="menu-item-342" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-342" data-userway-font-size="19"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/programs-projects/highway-improvement/" data-userway-font-size="23">Highway Improvements</a></li>
       <li id="menu-item-343" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-343" data-userway-font-size="19"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/programs-projects/multimodal-arterial-roads/" data-userway-font-size="23">Multimodal Arterials and Roads</a></li>
       <li id="menu-item-344" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-344" data-userway-font-size="19"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/programs-projects/port-of-oakland/" data-userway-font-size="23">Port of Oakland Infrastructure</a></li>
       <li id="menu-item-413" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-413" data-userway-font-size="19"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/programs-projects/transit/" data-userway-font-size="23">Transit</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
     <li id="menu-item-7700" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-7700" data-userway-font-size="16"><a href="/programs-projects/" data-userway-font-size="19">Programs</a>
     <ul class="sub-menu" data-userway-font-size="16">
       <li id="menu-item-4550" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-4550" data-userway-font-size="19"><a href="/programs-projects/bicycle-and-pedestrian/" data-userway-font-size="23">Bicycle and Pedestrian</a></li>
       <li id="menu-item-339" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-339" data-userway-font-size="19"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/programs-projects/commute-options-and-benefits/" data-userway-font-size="23">Commute Options and Benefits</a></li>
       <li id="menu-item-2714" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2714" data-userway-font-size="19"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/safe-routes-to-schools/" data-userway-font-size="23">Safe Routes to Schools</a></li>
       <li id="menu-item-345" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-345" data-userway-font-size="19"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/programs-projects/senior-disabled-transport/" data-userway-font-size="23">Senior and Disabled Transportation</a></li>
       <li id="menu-item-346" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-346" data-userway-font-size="19"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/programs-projects/studentpass/" data-userway-font-size="23">Student Transit Pass Pilot</a></li>
       <li id="menu-item-414" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-414" data-userway-font-size="19"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/programs-projects/transit-oriented-development/" data-userway-font-size="23">Transit Oriented Development</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-26" data-userway-font-size="14"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/get-involved/" data-userway-font-size="16">Get Involved  <i class="arrow down" data-userway-font-size="16"></i></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu" data-userway-font-size="14">
     <li id="menu-item-418" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-418" data-userway-font-size="16"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/get-involved/careers-jobs/" data-userway-font-size="19">Career Opportunities</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-419" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-419" data-userway-font-size="16"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/get-involved/contracting-doing-business/" data-userway-font-size="19">Contracting  Opportunities</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-3483" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-3483" data-userway-font-size="16"><a href="/get-involved/upcoming-meetings/" data-userway-font-size="19">Meetings</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-421" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-421" data-userway-font-size="16"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/get-involved/sign-up/" data-userway-font-size="19">Sign Up and Stay Informed</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-47" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-47" data-userway-font-size="14"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/news-publications/" data-userway-font-size="16">News&nbsp;and&nbsp;Publications&nbsp;<i class="arrow down" data-userway-font-size="16"></i></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu" data-userway-font-size="14">
     <li id="menu-item-423" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-423" data-userway-font-size="16"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/news-publications/e-newsletter/" data-userway-font-size="19">E-Newsletter</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-424" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-424" data-userway-font-size="16"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/expenditure-plans/" data-userway-font-size="19">Expenditure Plans</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-425" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-425" data-userway-font-size="16"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/news-publications/fact-sheets/" data-userway-font-size="19">Fact Sheets</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-2757" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2757" data-userway-font-size="16"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/news/" data-userway-font-size="19">News</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-2476" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2476" data-userway-font-size="16"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/news-publications/press-releases/" data-userway-font-size="19">Press Releases</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-426" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-426" data-userway-font-size="16"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/news-publications/reports/" data-userway-font-size="19">Reports</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-427" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-427" data-userway-font-size="16"><a href="http://stg.alamedactc.org/news-publications/signage/" data-userway-font-size="19">Signage</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </ul></div>     </nav>
```